# Google module conflict

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-visualization

In my Angular2 project I use 2 modules:

```
"@types/google.visualization": "0.0.40",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.29.1",
```

It creates conflict like:

```
ERROR in C:/.../ng-cli/src/app/app.component.ts (25,21): Namespace 'google' has no exported member 'visualization'.
ERROR in C:/.../ng-cli/src/app/app.component.ts (52,12): Property 'charts' does not exist on type 'typeof google'.
ERROR in C:/.../ng-cli/src/app/app.component.ts (145,30): Property 'visualization' does not exist on type 'typeof google'.
```

googlemaps declares namespace google.maps.

google.visualization declares namespace google and inside charts and visualization.

How to solve it correctly?

Comment: What is in line 25 of `app.component.ts`?

Comment: it's a variable declaration:   chartData: google.visualization.DataTable;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it by removing of google.visualization module. All declarations from its index.d.ts were moved to new file inside src directory and this new file was described in tsconfig.json in section "files" like "src/google-visualization.ts". Now it's fine work.